# GLM modeling error

Tags: r, glm

I have data (I will provide head of the data) and wanna model GLM on "accurancy". My R studio keeps freezing all the time I run the final code, the GLM one. I have no clue what to do and I am completly stucked..

```
ContractNr Year ValidFrom  ValidThru    Exposure EarnedPremium
1    3006024 2013  1.1.2013  31.3.2013 0,246575342   53,79877695
2    3006024 2013  1.4.2013  22.4.2013 0,060273973   13,48774798
3    3012819 2013  1.1.2013 31.12.2013           1   367,0053327
4    3012819 2014  1.1.2014 31.12.2014           1   367,0053327
5    3012819 2015  1.1.2015  26.4.2015 0,317808219   116,6373112
6    3014874 2013  1.1.2013  28.2.2013 0,161643836   57,71979747
YearlyNetPremium     ClaimNr ClaimDate ClaimYear NClaims   Incurred
1      218,1839288          NA                  NA       0          0
2      223,7740007          NA                  NA       0          0
3      367,0053327 61861914012 21.8.2013      2013       1 1390,86693
4      367,0053327          NA                  NA       0          0
5      367,0053327          NA                  NA       0          0
6       357,080103          NA                  NA       0          0
    Payments Reserve County ConstrYear EngPerfKW Weight BonusMalus Age Gender
1          0       0     GM       1999        40    975          0  51 female
2          0       0     GM       1999        40    975          0  51 female
3 1390,86693       0      L       2003       132   1834         -1  58 female
4          0       0      L       2003       132   1834         -1  59 female
5          0       0      L       2003       132   1834         -1  60 female
6          0       0     PE       2004        55   1318          0  79   male
  ClaimReason    Make Telematics CarAge G_EngPerfKW G_Weight G_Age
1          NA Renault          0     16          25      500    50
2          NA Renault          0     16          25      500    50
3           1    Audi          0     12         125     1500    50
4          NA    Audi          0     12         125     1500    50
5          NA    Audi          0     12         125     1500    60
6          NA    Opel          0     11          50     1000    70
```

What I want to do is for the "NClaims", which is binary one make weights and therefore make GLM. I have tried something similar with the machine learning (training/test data), it has worked.

```
library(caret)
library(FSelector)
set.seed(42)
dataset<-read.csv(file.choose(),header=T,sep=";")
str(dataset)
dataset$NClaims[is.na(dataset$NClaims)]<-names(which.max(table(dataset$NClaims)))
dataset$ClaimReason<-NULL
dataset$ClaimNr<-NULL
dataset$ClaimDate<-NULL
dataset$ClaimYear<-NULL
dataset$Incurred<-NULL
dataset$Payments<-NULL
dataset$Reserve<-NULL
colSums(is.na(dataset))
dataset$ValidFrom<-NULL
dataset$ValidThru<-NULL
dataset$County<-NULL
dataset$Gender<-NULL
dataset$Make<-NULL
weights_info_gain<-information.gain(NClaims ~ ., data=dataset)
weights_info_gain
weights_gain_ratio = gain.ratio(NClaims ~ ., data=dataset)
weights_gain_ratio
most_important_attributes <- cutoff.k(weights_gain_ratio, 20)
most_important_attributes
formula_with_most_important_attributes <- as.simple.formula(most_important_attributes, "NClaims")
formula_with_most_important_attributes
fitCtrl = trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=5, repeats=3)
modelGLM = train(formula_with_most_important_attributes, data=dataset, method="glm", trControl=fitCtrl, metric="Accuracy",na.action = na.pass)
```

I have thrown away date I was not sure if GLM gonna take (like "Make" or just whatever not numerical). Thanks for the help!!

Comment: If your main problem is R "freezing" when running the training model, are you sure it's not just that your models take a long time to run? You have asked for 3 x 5-fold cross-validation, that may take a long time with large data.

Comment: Yes, you do appear to be missing some clues. You have not yet recognized the input errors signaled by the commas in what should be numeric columns. You also appear to be using incurred columns to predict number of claims. That's clearly using one outcome to predict another.

Answer (score 0):

I tried `re-sampling data` from the question to create a larger `data` set for answering the question. The `code` seems to run fine on the `sample data set`:

- replaced the `commas` in `columns` '`YearlyNetPremium`', '`Exposure`', '`EarnedPremium`’, ‘`Incurred`’, ‘`Payments`’ etc. by a dot '.'
- Added `NA's` to `blank rows` (these are set to `NULL` later anyways)
- Convert `strings` to `date` or `year`

`Code` below seems to work with above sample `data`:

**Import libraries**

```
library(lubridate)
library(caret)
library(FSelector)
```

**Create sample data by sampling data from question**

```
ContractNr <- c(3006024, 3006024, 3012819, 3012819, 3012819, 3014874)
Year <- c(2013,2013,2013,2014,2015,2013)
ValidFrom <- c('1.1.2013', '1.4.2013', '1.1.2013', '1.1.2014', '1.1.2015', '1.1.2013')
ValidThru <- c('31.3.2013', '22.4.2013', '31.12.2013', '31.12.2014', '26.4.2015', '28.2.2013')
Exposure <-c(0.246575342, 0.060273973, 1,1,0.317808219, 0.161643836)
EarnedPremium <- c(53.79877695, 13.48774798, 13.48774798, 367.0053327, 116.6373112, 57.71979747)
YearlyNetPremium <- c(218.1839288, 223.7740007, 367.005332, 367.0053327, 367.0053327, 357.080103)
ClaimNr <- c(NA,NA,61861914012,NA,NA,NA)
ClaimDate <- c(NA,NA,'21.8.2013',NA,NA,NA)
ClaimYear <- c(NA,NA,2013,NA,NA,NA)
NClaims <- c(0,0,1,0,0,0)
Incurred <- c(0,0,1390.86693,0,0,0)
Payments <- c(0,0, 1390.86693, 0,0,0)
Reserve <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0)
County <- c('GM', 'GM', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'PE')
ConstrYear <- c(1999, 1999, 2003,2003,2003,2004 )
EngPerfKW <- c(40,40,132,132,132,55)
Weight <- c(975, 975, 1834,1834,1834,1318)
BonusMalus <- c(0,0,-1,-1,-1,0)
Age <- c(51,51,58,59,60,79)
Gender <- c('female','female','female','female','female','male')
ClaimReason <- c(NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA)
Make <- c('Renault','Renault','Audi','Audi','Audi','Opel' )
Telematics <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0)
CarAge <- c(16,16,12,12,12,11)
G_EngPerfKW <- c(25,25,125,125,125,50)
G_Weight <- c(500, 500, 1500, 1500, 1500, 1000)
G_Age <- c(50,50,50,50,60,70)


df <- data.frame(ContractNr,Year,ValidFrom,ValidThru,Exposure,EarnedPremium,YearlyNetPremium,ClaimNr,ClaimDate,
                 ClaimYear,Incurred,Payments,Reserve,County,ConstrYear,EngPerfKW,Weight,BonusMalus,
                 Age,Gender,ClaimReason,Make,Telematics,CarAge,G_EngPerfKW,G_Weight,G_Age )

# Sample to create a larger dataset
t <- df[sample(nrow(df), 100, replace = TRUE), ]
t['ContractNr'] = abs(floor(1e6*rnorm(100,sd=1)))
t['NClaims'] = floor(runif(100,0,1.9))
# Convert to date
t['ValidFrom'] = as.Date(t$ValidFrom, "%d.%m.%Y")
t['ValidThru'] = as.Date(t$ValidThru, "%d.%m.%Y")
t['ConstrYear'] = year(as.Date(as.character(t$ConstrYear), format = "%Y"))

t <- subset(t, select=-c(Reserve,Telematics,ClaimReason,ClaimNr,ClaimDate, ClaimYear))
dataset <- t
```

**Code from the question post above**

```
set.seed(42)
#dataset<-read.csv(file.choose(),header=T,sep=";")
str(dataset)
dataset$NClaims[is.na(dataset$NClaims)]<-names(which.max(table(dataset$NClaims)))

dataset$ClaimReason<-NULL
dataset$ClaimNr<-NULL
dataset$ClaimDate<-NULL
dataset$ClaimYear<-NULL
dataset$Incurred<-NULL
dataset$Payments<-NULL
dataset$Reserve<-NULL
colSums(is.na(dataset))
dataset$ValidFrom<-NULL
dataset$ValidThru<-NULL
dataset$County<-NULL
dataset$Gender<-NULL
dataset$Make<-NULL



weights_info_gain <- information.gain(NClaims ~ ., data=dataset)
wgr = gain.ratio(NClaims ~ ., data=dataset)
mia <- cutoff.k(wgr, 20)
fia <- as.simple.formula(mia, "NClaims")
fitCtrl = trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=5, repeats=3)
modelGLM = train(fia, data=dataset, method="glm", trControl=fitCtrl, metric="Accuracy",na.action = na.pass)
summary(modelGLM)
```

[image]